# laravel image optimizer file does not exists

Tags: php, laravel, production, file-not-found, image-optimization

I am using `spatie/laravel-image-optimizer` package to optimize my images.
I receive the error message:
`storage/app/public/files/car/9/km_declaration/2022/uE5DMCYh6hCuQXrOZ4yOSLCtLEnNdsE9e9OriNVw.jpg does not exist`

Although the file is there, and it can access it locally, in production it cannot find it.

I am using the optimizer as it supposted to be used, and I am using the filesystem public:

```
ImageOptimizer::optimize($this->url);
```

Do you have any guess why is it working locally with homestead but not on production?

(Folder permissions 755 on prod)

Update:
The code: `ImageOptimizer::optimize($this->url);` is run from a cron job.
If I do `file_exists($url)` from the controller I got true, but false from the job. I think that is the source of my issue.

Comment: if the file doesn't exist, how can we help you ? You can confirm the non existence of the file by encapsulating that line with `if (file_exists($this->url)) {`. Regarding the folder permission, who is the set owner of the folder for you to use 755 instead of 775

Comment: the thing is that the file does exist in that location, just the code is not able to find it

Comment: Can you add to your question the dump of the value `$this->url` in local and in production ?

Comment: @N69S It is the same. Now  what I could investigate, is that file_exists($url) returns true on the controller but false from cron job, using the same url. Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: would have been faster to show as an example of the value. since the error is triggered between the difference of environment, i suggest you either do a " cd path/of/project" as the first instruction of the cron before the "schedule:run" or use in your code the helper "base_path()" like this `ImageOptimizer::optimize(base_path($this->url));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the storage folder, you need to set permissions 775
**chmod -R 775 storage**

Comment: I did change the permission but still the same error :(

Comment: Actually I had to do 2 things, first change the permission as suggested in this answer, and also I needed to add the public_path when I called the optimizer:
            'ImageOptimizer::optimize(public_path().$this->url);'